# Angular block unauthorized HTTP calls

Tags: angular, web-applications

I don't know if this security hole is even possible or I am just being paranoid after a spicy dinner.

In a typical Angular app, there are any number of unknown npm packages pulled in transitively.  I wonder if some dodgy npm package could take my application data and whisk it off to some server without my knowledge.

It is trivial to bypass the HTTP_INTERCEPTORS so they are not much help as a security guard.

Is the only hard solution to use Windows firewall rules on the PC where the browser/app will be run?

Comment: Yes, as a developer you put trust into third party packages to not be malicious. Either you can simply trust the devs behind the tool (such as the Google team behind Angular), or you'll have to verify the source code yourself and all the dependencies they have. When the community finds that an npm package is malicious, it will be reported and you as a developer will be noted about it when running npm commands (even if the dependency is deep down in the hierarchy).

Comment: As for the website users, they put their trust in the site developers whenever they give sensitive data. They can use firewalls, but that is not going to get them far for protecting their data.

Comment: @ShamPooSham my question was about transitively loaded packages way down the line.  Of course we can trust Angular, bootstrap, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right to be worried about this matter. Indeed there are many `npm` packages that may contain dangerous code. In general I suggest you to use only the "very well known packages". There are software that can help you with, like "bytesafe". Here is a more detailed article on how it works https://bytesafe.dev/posts/npm-security-issues-2021/ (no marketing intended). If you don't intend to use such software, than you should always check for your packages by using: `npm audit` (example: `npm audit –audit-level=critical`) and update the packages accordingly or use `npm audit fix`.

I saw you are talking about "Windows firewall rules". The server where your site sit may be Linux or any other kind of OS. There is an entire universe about servers security and security architectures. Depends a lot if you are in the cloud or on-premise for example. So there are security best practices for each approach and you should follow those according your context.